# How to set Heroku app to specific Postgres schema?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

There is one database configured in Heroku.
The Django application connects fine, but the tables are put in the public schema.

These tables should be in the 'invoices' schema. That schema is already created, but it's empty. Below is what the settings.py currently look like:

```
DATABASES["default"] = dj_database_url.config(
    conn_max_age=600,
    ssl_require=True,
)
DB_SEARCH_PATH = os.environ.get("DB_SEARCH_PATH", "invoices")
```

Answer (score 0):

The search path was not set. I added it using the following method:

```
@receiver(connection_created)
def set_search_path(sender, **kwargs):
    """Store tables in a separate schema."""
    from django.conf import settings

    search_path = settings.DB_SEARCH_PATH

    conn = kwargs.get("connection")
    if search_path and conn is not None:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SET search_path='{}'".format(search_path))
```

It listens to the connection_created signal and sets the search path using the DB_SEARCH_PATH var.